# iFrame ads from site to site

Tags: iframe

How I can make the iFrame ads from site A to site B 
not like this:  `<iframe src="http://www.site.com"></iframe>` 
Example:

```
site A
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-3434343507";
/* site */
google_ad_slot = "343435270";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>

site B
--iFrame--
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-3434343507";
/* site */
google_ad_slot = "343435270";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
--iFrame--
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, you don't since this will more than likely have your account closed down. If you want ads on the 2nd domain then execute the JavaScript as Google intends.

Quote from Google:

> As a result, we’ve modified our Ad Behavior policy to the following:
>   AdSense code may not be altered, nor may the standard behavior,
>   targeting or delivery of ads be manipulated in any way that is not
>   explicitly permitted by Google. This includes but is not limited to
>   the following: clicking Google ads may not result in a new browser
>   window being launched, nor may Google ads be placed in an IFRAME.